# Can Dynamics Crm PartyList store an emailaddress

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrm

I have fields in activity form for email. It contains "to, cc and bcc" fields that are all fields of the type PartyList

The question is: Can I only store entity values like contact or account or can I also just store a email address which is not associated to any contact or account in the system?

Here is a picture explaining what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://paul-way.com/sending-unresolved-emails/

Comment: Hi, I have seen this and this is only related to the Email entity in CRM. I have a completely custom activity entity that is a child to Email which is also activity entity. The problem is that this particular email setting "allow unresolved email address" does not get inherited to my custom entity.

Comment: understood, this is quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this article](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2015/09/07/working-with-dynamics-crm-activity-party-lists-in-c--plugins) it appears that the answer is yes via the `addressUsed` field.

```
Entity email = _sdk.Retrieve("email", emailId, new ColumnSet("to"));

EntityCollection to = email.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("to");
if (to != null)
{
    to.Entities.ToList().ForEach(party =>
    {
        EntityReference partyId = party.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("partyid");
        bool isDeleted = party.GetAttributeValue<bool>("ispartydeleted");
        string addressUsed = party.GetAttributeValue<string>("addressused");

        // Do something...
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a server side solution, I am trying to achieve this in client side where the field validation occurs. I would never get to that step of saving the record if the client validation is blinking. You can not use "addressused" unless you sign this record on some contact or account which we do not want to do.